# for each statement and for each row after triggers return value

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm learning triggers in Postgres using Plpgsql language and I don't fully understand how the for each statement triggers and for each row after triggers functions work.

In before each row triggers there are 3 return values:  NEW for the INSERT/UPDATE operation to be executed, OLD for the DELETE operation to be executed and NULL to not execute any operation.

In for each statement and for each row after triggers functions the only possible return value is NULL, so my questions are:

-In for each statement triggers, how do you tell if you want the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operation on the table to be executed or not?

-In for each row after triggers, how do you tell if you want to roll back or not?

Comment: It all spelled out here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) as pointed out before.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I read that page of documentation and the questions I wrote are what I don't understand about that page.

Comment: Pretty straight forward: 'Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row).'  and 'The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error.'

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks, now is all clear, so errors/exceptions are what's used to handle both roll backs in after triggers and deciding if an operation has to be executed or not in before triggers.

Comment: No returning `NULL` in a before trigger skips the operation in it and any following triggers. That is not raising an error or exception.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver According to the selected answer the only way to determine if an operation is going to be executed or not in a before statement level trigger is if an exception has been raised or not, as you cannot specify that you want to skip the data modification in a statement level trigger but raising an exception would effectively be like skipping the data modification.

Comment: I should have been clearer, a before row trigger can use a return null to not complete the desired action(INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE). Exceptions are the only way in a statement level(before or after) trigger to abort the operation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I guess I should have specified I meant only before statement triggers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you cannot specify that you want to skip the data modification in a statement level trigger
- to force a `ROLLBACK` in a trigger, `RAISE` an exception

Comment: Thanks! I have one last question: if you raise an exception in a statement level before trigger, does that mean that the operation gets aborted? and would that effectively be like skipping the data modification?

Comment: Yes. The trigger always runs in the same transaction as the triggering statement, so an error in the trigger will rollback both.